# Fourier transforms similar $\Rightarrow$ functions similar?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis

I am wondering if there is a theorem that states something like the following?

If
$$\big|\;\tilde f(\omega)-\tilde g(\omega)\,\big| < \varepsilon\qquad \forall\omega$$
then there exists a $\delta(\varepsilon)$ such that
$$\big|\; f(x)- g(x)\,\big| < \delta(\varepsilon)\qquad \forall x $$
where $\tilde f(\omega)$ and $\tilde g(\omega)$ are the Fourier transforms of the $L^2(\mathbb R)$ functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.

It is just an intuition, since a the fourier transform is invertible and unique. The extrem situation 
$$\big|\;\tilde f(\omega)-\tilde g(\omega)\,\big| =0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad \big|\; f(x)- g(x)\,\big| =0$$
holds trivially.

A naive way to find such a theorem is to say that we have a function $\eta(\omega)$ with $|\eta(\omega)|<\varepsilon$ and $\tilde g(\omega)=\tilde f(\omega)+\eta(\omega)$. Then one can easily derive
$$\big|\;\tilde f(\omega)-\tilde g(\omega)\,\big| <\varepsilon \quad \Rightarrow \quad \big|\; f(x)- g(x)\,\big| < \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int|\eta(\omega)|\;\text d \omega$$

Comment: One of the problems is that even if $\eta$ is small, its integral may easily be infinite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false. For example, take a smooth compactly supported function $f(x)$ and set $F_\epsilon(x)=\epsilon f(\epsilon x)$. Then $|F_\epsilon(x)|\le \epsilon\max|f(x)|$, but
$$
\widetilde F_\epsilon(p)=\frac1{2\pi}\int e^{-ipx}\epsilon f(\epsilon x)dx=
\frac1{2\pi}\int e^{-ipy/\epsilon}f(y)dy=\widetilde f(p/\epsilon),
$$
and the maximum of $|\widetilde F_\epsilon(p)|$ is independent of $\epsilon$.